# SharePoint Login prompt cancel redirect

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, iis, windows-authentication

I have configured FBA Form authentication and also using **window authentication**. For form authentication, Until user logged in to site, they stay to login page.

But when we do window authentication, it prompts for authentication. If we pass username and password, it redirect to home page but if we press **cancel**, it shows **access denied page** at url http://servername/_windows/default.aspx, but my req is to redirect page to **login page again**.

is there any to achieve this?

is it possible to redirect to FBA login page from login cancel button?